# UI is disturb due to default call in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

My application have calling functionality. When making call,it goes to default phone app. Now during on going call, I am accessing my app, at that time my app shows green bar over navigation bar. If I go to next detail screen, all UI is getting disturbed.

Comment: Add screen shot for more information

Comment: add some detail of your code or add some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three choices here to fix your VC UI:

**Firs:**
you can set up the autoresize masks in code or strotyboard.

**Second:** use didChangeStatusBarFrame:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame {
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height == 40) {
        // Do adjustment
    }
    else if  ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height == 20 && oldStatusBarHeight == 40){ // you should keep oldStatusBarHeight 
        // Do adjustment
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

**Third:** register for a Change StatusBarFrame notification in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarFrameChanged:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarFrameWillChange:) name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
```

And adjust your VC size in `statusBarFrameWillChange` and `statusBarFrameChanged`.

Comment: I have checked above with my project. When there is a call and I open my app, status bar for phone call overlap my view. I have done auto sizing but still it overlap the navigation bar.

Comment: Dude iOS7 will get released soon, and the status bar became part of the nav bar and  your problem will a  history ;) .